# Why give me something in the review queue where the only option is "skip"?

Tags: bug, review-audit, locked-posts, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing I came across [image: this].

My only option was to "skip". Why did this show up?

Comment: You can't reopen a locked question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know I can't reopen a locked question, so why did this show up?

Comment: I'm not sure...

Comment: Did this review show up a few days ago (on Nov 6)?

Comment: @ArthurFischer It showed up right before I posted it here

Comment: This is quite odd. The moderator timeline shows that a reopen review **audit** was opened on Nov 6, but since the only option available to almost all users is to skip, it hasn't been completed.  (Well, a moderator can complete the audit...) Here is a direct link to the review: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/518503).

Comment: Similar occurrences noted on Meta Stack Exchange: [Review Audit with no option to flag, downvote or comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187533), and [Nothing to do in this review but “No action needed”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187971) (the latter is marked as a duplicate of the former, but perhaps matches the current situation better).

Comment: @Arthur I counted 16 "Skip"s for that audit so far. It seems quite desperate to be acted on.